# How do I sum values between a date and that same date plus 12 weeks?

Tags: sql, date, group-by, sum

I have data at the Cust_ID and Week_Date level with sales_dollars. Each Week_Date represents the sales_dollars for that week. I want to sum the dollars for each Cust_ID for the next 8 weeks. I want the final data at the Cust_ID and Week_Date level. Is that possible using sql?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far???  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: select 
  Week_Date, 
  cust_id, 
  sales, 
  sum(sales) over (partition by cust_id order by Week_Date
    range between interval '0' week preceding and interval '10' weeks preceding) as Sales_10Wks from mydata

Comment: I actually want it not to be 'preceeding' but after the date. but I thought if I could get this to work, I could research how to change that.

Comment: Which dbms is this?  SQL is just a language used by multiple database vendors.  Each of them has their own syntax.  It's useless if someone posted code, but you can't use it because it's for the wrong vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a window functions:

```
select t.*, 
       sum(sales) over (partition by cust_id
                        order by week_date
                        rows between current row and 7 following
                       ) as sales_8weeks
from t;
```

This assumes that all weeks have data.  If you want to put a range in by date, you can do that but the exact syntax varies by database.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, there are missing weeks. I am using a cvs file from Hadoop. Does that help?